# Error 403 al enviar datos desde Android en local

Tags: php, java, android-studio, xampp, windows-server-2016

estoy realizando pruebas de envío a un nuevo servidor que he migrado, el servidor tiene Windows Server 2016, instalé XAMPP y el script que envía los datos a SQL Server esta en Php.
Al momento de enviar los datos desde java usando Volley me sale el siguiente error:

```
E/Volley: [814] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://94.72.*.*:8080/food/access.php
```

En el antiguo servidor no tengo este problema, ya tengo habilitado el permiso de salida para el puerto 8080 en el firewall, ¿Me falta algo por configurar?

Answer (score 0):

Pude ver lo que ocasiona dicha respuesta, el antivirus estaba detectando la ip del api como sospechosa, le coloque una exclusion y se solucionó.